# failed to deploy on firebase my project but the deployment is success in visual studio code

Tags: angular, firebase, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to deploy a project with firebase but it's not working.
when i deploy on vscode:
[image]

and the link testhosting-8a534.web.app not working
[image]

my firbase.json
[image]

the structure of my project
[image]
[image]

Please, i dont understand why my deployment not working.
Please help me!

Comment: If I read correctly your files are under `dist/hebergement` and not under `dist`.